# PHP - Reach a certain value in array

Tags: php, arrays

An API I use sent me back  an object/array (not sure).
this is the info i get back using `print_out($arr)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [callID] => 40
        [PairCallLegId] => 
        [CallsCount] => 4
        [LocalName] => 151204
        [RemoteName] => 15740
        [type] => 1
        [isOut] => 0
        [FirstName] => Boris
        [lastName] => Ostrovsky
        [AvgMos] => 3.7432666239999963
        [AvgQoe] => 
        [AvgPL] => 
        [AvgJitter] => 
        [AvgVideoQP] => 
        [AvgBDW] => 1200
        [AvgFrameRate] => 
        [AvgTotalPkt] => 102433.80945757998
        [AvgTotalBytes] => 
    )
)
```

Im trying to reach the value inside "CallsCount" (should be 4)

I tried to use 
`$arr[0]["CallsCount"]`
and
`$arr["0"]["CallsCount"]`
and even
`$arr[0]->CallsCount`

None works. i get `Internal Server Error (500)` every time.

What should i do?

Comment: show some more code? Problem might be somewhere else

Comment: You should use: `$arr[0]["CallsCount"]`, Can you enable errors, and tell us which statement is actually causing that error?

Comment: `$arr[0]["CallsCount"]` should work, debug your code, error doesn't seem to be related with this

Comment: you should check the error log, server error 500 is just indicative. The error log will have the exact error and even the particular bit of code that triggered it.. better even, turn display_error on